# Using airline FF program shopping button (Chrome) on hotel websites - Double-dip?

Tags: hotels, loyalty-programs, american-airlines

asking if anyone tried this.
Talking about Shopping button extensions from FF programs (AAdvantage eShopping, United MileagePlus etc.) They sometimes have hotel websites possible for mileage collection. For example, AAdvantage has parkplaza.com. Park Plaza is a brand that is part of Radisson Rewards hotel membership.
If I book Park Plaza stay on parkplaza.com with AAdvatage eShopping button activated, will it earn both Radisson Rewards (basic and promotions) and AAdvantage miles?
Thank you

Comment: Not answering directly because I don’t know it for a fact, but I suppose you would. My impression is that AAdvantage eShopping is just a site using affiliate links to send you to the site and get a commission, which is then turned into miles. The site you buy from doesn’t even know you are getting miles, so shouldn’t handle your booking any differently.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have experience with AAdvantage, but Delta has similar program which I use.

The answer is "it depends". You need to check the fine print for a specific hotel booking rate you're getting when redirecting from AAdvantage. Some of those rates will not earn rewards, while if you booked the same rate (for the same price) at hotel's website, it would earn rewards.

In my experience this depends on the hotel chain policy, and not on a specific booking.